# HttpCookie gets messsed up in hebrew

Tags: c#, asp.net, hebrew

Let me explain my project first of all.
Its a form with some information that I add in to textboxs and a signature field.
When you click on the signature it redirects you to another page where you sign and then goes back to the form and puts the signature in an image.

Point is when I go to the signature page I put the Form information in to a cookie so I can put them back on when I return from the signature page.

The problem is when it gets to the other page the cookie gets messed up content wise. If I try to write some simple hebrew on the page there is no problem.

This is the code that saves the cookie.

```
 protected void ReCapture(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string s = "";

    foreach (Control c in form1.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            s += ((TextBox)c).Text + ":" + ((TextBox)c).ID + ",";
        }
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(Image))
        {
            s += ((Image)c).ImageUrl + ":" + ((Image)c).ID + ",";
        }

    }


    Response.Cookies.Remove("Controls");

    HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("Controls",s.Remove(s.Length - 2));
    hc.Expires.AddHours(2);
    hc.Path = "/";
    Response.Cookies.Add(hc);

    Response.Redirect("SignaturePage.aspx?id=" + ((Control)sender).ID);
}
```

This is the signature page code(practically nothing)

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Session["TheSignature"] = Request.Form["TheData"];
    Response.Redirect("Test.aspx");
 }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I looked up UrlEncoding and isn't it just the encoding that does in the url with %20?..my output is just a wrongly encoded hebrew.

Comment: Use UrlEncoding or Base64 encoding.  ... but why use a cookie for this? Surely this information could be easily held on the server in the Session?

Comment: Well I tried session and the information simply disappeared after it got redirected. I've never seen it happen before like this but the image data gets through and the hebrew data doesn't. Maybe its also because of the encoding but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks, UrlEncoding worked. Glad I learned something new.